# Fading between pages with React and React Transition Group

Tags: reactjs, react-starter-kit, react-transition-group

I'm trying to fade on entry and leave between pages in React using [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/).

Inspired by the post [Applying React.js CSS Transitions on initial render](https://web-design-weekly.com/2015/02/05/applying-react-js-css-transitions-initial-render/) I did this for the root component loaded by every page:

```
import React from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import s from './About.less';

class About extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mounted: false,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.setState({
            mounted: true,
        });
    };
    render() {
        const child = this.state.mounted ? <h1>Hello world</h1> : null;

        return (
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName="example"
                transitionAppear
                transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
            >
                {child}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(s)(About);
```

And in the css I have:

```
.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

When the component is mounted, the element is shown, but without any entering transition. Am I doing something wrong there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appear Transition will not be effective in/after ComponentDidMount().

If you want to see the transition after ComponentDidMount() use Enter/Leave transition.

In your case instead of componentDidMount() if you keep your code in componentWillMount() it will work fine. I have changed your code. Hope this helps.

```
class About extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mounted: false
    };
}
componentWillMount ()  {
    this.setState({
        mounted: true
    });
};
render() {
    const child = this.state.mounted ? <h1>Hello world</h1> : null;

    return (
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="example"
            transitionAppear

        >
            {child}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    );
}
```

}

For reference [React Page Transition](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/react-page-transition-animations-9d18c90a9831)